# Java Runtime version for JDK12

Tags: java, jshell, java-12

It's not really an error but when I am checking the runtime version it gives me the following, does that mean am I doing something wrong?

```
jshell> Runtime.version()
$3 ==> 12.0.1+12
```

Comment: Why do you find this wrong? It's the Java version that you're executing the `jshell` for, right? Your expectation would clarify the question a bit further.

Comment: What you might also be interested in [What does the 4th number mean in Java 9's version string scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156016/what-does-the-4th-number-mean-in-java-9s-version-string-scheme)

Comment: [Time-Based Release Versioning](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/322)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Current version of OpenJDK = 12.0.1+12

Nothing is amiss. Version 12.0.1 Build 12 is the currently shipping version of the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) implementation of [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition).

See this screenshot of the [AdoptOpenJDK website](https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk12&jvmVariant=hotspot). Notice the version number `12.0.1+12` circled here in orange.

[image: screenshot of AdoptOpenJDK web site download page showing current version of Java as 10.0.1+12]

To understand the semantics of the version numbering for Java 10 and later, see [*JEP 322: Time-Based Release Versioning*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/322).